# Find $\ Df(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Find $\ Df(x,y,z)$ if $\ f(x,y,z) = (xz, y^2+z)$

I got confused, is it asking me for the domain in which the function is defined or about some sort of derivative?

Comment: The domain is clearly all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, The problem is asking for the derivative, which is a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)=(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z))$ where $f_1,f_2:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ are the coordinate functions. Then $Df(x,y,z)$ is a type of derivative operator, and can be computed as follows:
$$Df(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}$$
This derivative operator maps a vector function to a matrix consisting of all first order partial derivatives of the component functions of the input vector function. This matrix is known as the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $f$. Note that, in your case, $f_1(x,y,z)=xz$ and $f_2(x,y,z)=y^2+z$.